# Dart editor visual theme - blue text hard to read on black background

Tags: dart, dart-editor

I would like to set a visual theme in the Dart editor with a black background, but there is always certain text that appears blue, which makes it difficult to read. For example, quoted text in HTML documents appears blue. So, in the following text:

meta charset="utf-8"

"utf-8" is blue (including quotes). I have tried to fix this by creating my own theme, and by editing the XML file in dart\plugins\com.google.dart.tools.deploy_0.2.9.r16323\themes, but to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can star this bug here: http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7510

Answer (score 1):

You're right. It's a problem. As @tomaszkubacki said, please star this bug (http://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=7510). That's the only answer I have for the time being.